# Determine location given a dictionary with lists inside of a list

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm new here and I need some help with some code I've been working on because I've gotten myself lost and am now just confused.

First, I created a dictionary based on some help from this website. A sample of my dictionary looks like this:

```
length = {'A': [(0,21), (30,41), (70,80)] 'B': [(0,42), (70,80)]..etc}
```

I have a file that I would like to use to iterate over my dictionary that contains this information:

```
A    32
B    15
etc
```

What I want to do is to take the first feature in my file and match it to the key of my dictionary. Once I have it matched, I want to to see which range the number in my file matches to. For example, the first feature in my file would match to A and the second range. That means I would want my output to show the name (A) and display 2 because it matched to the second range.

I've tried my code below:

```
import csv
with open('Exome_agg_cons_snps_pct_RefSeq_HGMD_reinitialized.txt') as f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f,delimiter="\t")
    for row in reader:
        snppos = row['snp_rein']
        name = row['isoform']
        snpos = int(snppos)
        if name in exons:
            y = exons[name]
            if y[0] <= snpos <=y[1]:
                print name,snppos
```

This, however, doesn't give me any output. I'm not sure what is wrong with my code. I am new though. I think I might be missing something. Also, I realize that my code won't do what I want it to do (tell me what range it matched to). I was thinking of using the `.index()` function but I'm not sure I can use it in the case I have. Any suggestions?

Comment: There's only one line in your code that generates output.  If you're not getting that far, it suggests that one of your `if` statements is failing.  Try putting a `print` statement *outside* each `if` statement to see what the values you're testing actually are.

Comment: Ah, my second if statement is the problem. I'll have to work to correct it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your list in the dictionary is ordered then this method will work

1. The `enumerate` method provides two output one will be index and the next one will be value .
2. Since the value here is list we are iterating over the lists[one list at a time ].
3. We are using max method to find the maximum of the list
4. Then we are comparing it with the value from the text .
5. If so we will print the index +1 and name

**code:**

```
for sd, i  in enumerate(exons[name]):
    if snpos<=max(i) and snpos>=min(i):
        print sd+1,name
        break
```

Comment: Can you share a brief explanation on how this works?

Comment: Put `A 25` in your input and you'll get a false match.

Comment: @alexis that range is not covered in the dictonary

Comment: That's my point: Your code can't distinguish `A 35` (in second range) from `A 25` (not in a range).

Comment: @alexis now it will work as you intended thanks for the look out

Answer (score 1):

You just need to loop over the spans in a dict value. It's nicer to let the for-loop split them already:

```
for row in reader:
    snppos = row['snp_rein']
    name = row['isoform']
    if name in exons:
        for low, high in exons[name]:
             if low <= snppos <= high:
                 print name, low, high
                 break    # Since exons can't overlap, go to next row immediately
```

If you need the index in the exon list rather than the span (e.g., index `2` rather `(70, 80)`), then add `enumerate`:

```
    ...
        for i, (low, high) in enumerate(exons[name]):
             if low <= snppos <= high:
                 print name, i
                 break
```

Comment: You are completely correct. I let that one slide because I actually needed a way to bin those that didn't fit in a particular range to an exon anyway and now I can stay consistent.